# How to fix 'require() : failed opening required .../wp-includes/post.php ' error when I switch between two themes?

Tags: wordpress

When installing a theme in `wordpress` and activating it I get these errors:

```
Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\mywp/wp-includes/post.php): failed to open  
stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywp\wp-settings.php on    
line 166  
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\mywp/wp-  
includes/post.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in    
C:\xampp\htdocs\mywp\wp-settings.php on line 166
```

to fix this I put `post.php` file in `wp-includes` folder but after refreshing page, I get another error:

```
Warning: Use of undefined constant REQUEST_URI - assumed 'REQUEST_URI' (this  
will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywp\wp-  
content\themes\canvas\functions.php on line 73
```

and a `php` script is added at the beginning of `functions.php`.
finally I removed that script and then theme was installed properly.
I installed `wordpress 5.2.2` again but when I want to switch to another theme
these errors happen again.
I want to know why these errors happen and what's the solution.

Comment: It seems that your WordPress setup is corrupted. Try reinstalling WordPress (Dashboard > Updates) and see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: I reinstalled (updated) wordpress 5.2.2 but the problem still exists.

Comment: If this problem only happens when activating a specific theme, then you'll want to get in touch with its developer and report the issue so they can help you debug it.

Comment: This problem isn't related to a specific theme and happens whenever I install a theme.